# Bootstrap super poner menu desplegable en la version movil por encima del contenido de abajo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, menú

> Mi problema surge al poner la version pequeña (movil) con el menu, ya sabeis que con bootstrap cuando se aumenta el tamaño a un menu se convierte en un boton con un desplegable con el icono de tres rayitas, bueno pues mi problema que ese botoncito cuando le doy a desplegar me echa para abajo el contenido que esta directamente abajo del menu, y lo que quiero es que se superponga encima del contenido que esta abajo, porque como lo tengo montado ahora mismo lo que hace es empujarme todo el contenido de abajo el menu hacia abajo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Maquetado v.1</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<style>
    .efecto_boton{
        border: 1px solid orange; /* Color del borde, debe ser más oscuro que fondo */
        background: orange; /* Fondo */
        border-radius: 6px;  /* Bordes redondos */
        box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.7), inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.9);  /* Sombra del texto */
        /*text-align: center;   Alineación del texto */
    }
    .menu{
        border: 1px solid green; /* Color del borde, debe ser más oscuro que fondo */
        background: green; /* Fondo */
        border-radius: 6px;  /* Bordes redondos */
        box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.7), inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.9);  /* Sombra del texto */
        /*text-align: center;   Alineación del texto */
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        z-index: 0;

    }

    .imagen_prueba{
        background-image: url('https://www.tuexperto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/fondo-de-pantalla-paisaje-768x432.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;


    }
</style>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- tiitutlo -->
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 efecto_boton">
                <h1 class="text-primary text-center " >Maquetado v.1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>


                <!-- menu -->
                <nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light menu">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
<!-- fin menu -->

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 text-left">
                <!-- col izq -->
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas adipisci magni ullam, quam aliquam mollitia. Aperiam quod cupiditate, aliquid illo expedita, libero corporis dolorum delectus alias, suscipit mollitia, quisquam soluta!</p>

                <imgS src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-center">
            <!-- col cent -->

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>

                <div class="container-fluid imagen_prueba">
                    g
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>fd

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-3 text-right">
            <!-- col der -->

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita perspiciatis at quos voluptas eos, sed veniam eligendi, omnis dignissimos excepturi adipisci explicabo dicta suscipit ad iure itaque deserunt ducimus sapiente!</p>


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Asi que si alguien sabe como superponer el menu a el cuerpo de la pagina le estaria muy agradecido, he intentado muchas cosas y no lo he logradoo. Tambien he encontrado algo de una propiedad CSS llamada z-index o algo asi, pero no se usarla de forma correcta por lo que veo. Muchas gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Aplicando "z-index:1", estableciendo "position:absolute", creando una clase para el cuerpo del contenido ".cuerpo" estableciendo distancia con la cabecera "padding-top:100px" es una forma de solucionarlo. Aquí con la modificación:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Maquetado v.1</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<style>
    .efecto_boton{
        border: 1px solid orange; /* Color del borde, debe ser más oscuro que fondo */
        background: orange; /* Fondo */
        border-radius: 6px;  /* Bordes redondos */
        box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.7), inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.9);  /* Sombra del texto */
        /*text-align: center;   Alineación del texto */
    }
    .menu{
        border: 1px solid green; /* Color del borde, debe ser más oscuro que fondo */
        background: green; /* Fondo */
        border-radius: 6px;  /* Bordes redondos */
        box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.7), inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.9);  /* Sombra del texto */
        /*text-align: center;   Alineación del texto */
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .imagen_prueba{
        background-image: url('https://www.tuexperto.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/fondo-de-pantalla-paisaje-768x432.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .cuerpo{padding-top: 100px}
</style>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- tiitutlo -->
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 efecto_boton">
                <h1 class="text-primary text-center " >Maquetado v.1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>


                <!-- menu -->
                <nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light menu">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
<!-- fin menu -->

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row cuerpo">
            <div class="col-3 text-left">
                <!-- col izq -->
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas adipisci magni ullam, quam aliquam mollitia. Aperiam quod cupiditate, aliquid illo expedita, libero corporis dolorum delectus alias, suscipit mollitia, quisquam soluta!</p>

                <imgS src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-center">
            <!-- col cent -->

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo in nesciunt quas architecto minus inventore debitis modi harum vero veritatis unde molestias, cum tenetur doloremque et est quae laudantium soluta.</p>

                <div class="container-fluid imagen_prueba">
                    g
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>fd

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-3 text-right">
            <!-- col der -->

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita perspiciatis at quos voluptas eos, sed veniam eligendi, omnis dignissimos excepturi adipisci explicabo dicta suscipit ad iure itaque deserunt ducimus sapiente!</p>


            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```